# Recommended approach to synchronize data to a different system

Tags: .net, sql-server, data-synchronization

What is the best way to update the data between two different systems?  My scenario is as below,
1) System1 (MSSql 2016) - this is my master application/db where the data is created; application developed using .net technology.
2) System2 (MSSql NA) - this is an 'Sales analytics' system which would source data from different systems, one of the source is System1/db1.

The objective is to update the data from Db1 to Db2, the updates can have minor delays.  The 'Sales analytics' system has API's that exposes endpoints using which it is possible to update the data.

Given the above scenario what are the available mechanisms to synchronize data?  While researching this i came across 'Sql CLR' (considering there are api endpoints), is this preferred approach, or, is there better way of doing this?
Notes:
1)  Minor delays in update is acceptable, however the objective is whenever there is change an attempt should be made to immediately synchronize.
2)  The data volume and the frequency of changes are small - so looking for a simpler but maintainable solution.

Regards,
SPM

Comment: Just use SQL Server's replication feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication

Comment: As Dai says SQL replication is a good approach and no coding necessary. But that replicates the entire database with the same tables. From your description, I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for. If you need to merge this data with other data sources to create an analytics system, you could also use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) to transform and copy data between SQL servers.